# Mongoose $or query with $near doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to run an `$or` query but whenever I use `$near` in one of the `$or` clauses, the query returns `0` results.

Here is my code:

```
params = { $or: [
  { loc: { '$near': { 
    '$geometry': { 
      type : "Point" ,
      coordinates : [ -0.127500 , 51.507220 ] 
    }, 
    '$maxDistance': 1000 
    } } }, 
  { categories: { $in: ['Services'] } }
] };
var query = Activity.find(params).populate({path: '_place'});
query.limit(10).exec('find', function(err, items) {
...
});
```

Comment: So what returns if you run either query condition in the `$or` on it's own? Or more importantly the `$near` query itself. Otherwise there is nothing wrong with using `$or` in this context. Except "limit" will probably not do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Both queries work well independently.

Comment: Show some data from each result so others can test. Nothing looks wrong here to me.

Comment: What do you mean by show some data?

Comment: What I ( and the upvote on the comment means agreement ) mean and therefore I am asking is to edit your question to include "two" sample documents returned by your indepent queries. That way we can run them outselves and see if what you are saying is true. Or at least see what is wrong with what your are trying. Point is "it works for the rest of us". So show the data and prove us wrong.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, running '$or' query with many `tags` returns documents containing those tags and running just the `$near` query returns the nearest `document` but both returns 0 `documents`.

Comment: Did anyone find any solution? I am also getting the same issue.